# How to call CbprMessage.validate for a pacs.008.001.08 using PaymentComponents SDK

Tags: paymentcomponents-finaplo-sdk

This question concerns the PaymentComponents SDK.

Using the Payment Components ISO20022 library, what parameters into the `CbprMessage.validate` method to specify in order to validate a `pacs.008.001.08` message according to the CBPR+ rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter to specify should be `CbprXsd.PACS_008`.

Here's a snippet

```
CbprMessage cbprMessage = new CbprMessage(new BusinessApplicationHeader02(), new FIToFICustomerCreditTransfer08());

cbprMessage.parseXml(xml);

ValidationErrorList validationErrorList = cbprMessage.validate(CbprMessage.CbprMsgType.PACS_008);
```